# Threejs rendering an FBX Object not working. - undefined 404 (Not found)

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, webxr

I have a set of .fbx objects that I'm trying to load through FBXLoader on a WebXR App.

```js
window.fbxLoader.load("/assets/modelate_FBX/Vaza%208067134/Vaza 8067134.fbx", function( object ) {
    const flower = this.scene.children.find(c => c.name === 'sunflower');
    window.sunflower = this.scene;
});
```

The problem is that whenever i try running the app, I get the following console error:

```plaintext
undefined:1 GET http://localhost:8887/assets/modelate_FBX/Vaza%208067134/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

I am pretty sure the object path is right, as I previously managed to render GLtf files. But I need to render the FBX aswell.

I'm expecting the need to define a path for the texture models. But to be honest I'm kinda lost.

Comment: Take a look at my answer

Comment: Also check out my edit to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Never define your object path as `localhost`! This will never work. Instead, but you path as `/assets/modelate_FBX/Vaza%208067134/Vaza 8067134.fbx`.

Here is how you`FBXLoader` would work:

```js
window.fbxLoader.load("/assets/modelate_FBX/Vaza%208067134/Vaza 8067134.fbx", function( object ) {
    const flower = this.scene.children.find(c => c.name === 'sunflower');
    window.sunflower = this.scene;
});
```

Comment: i did that aswell before

window.fbxLoader.load("../assets/modelate_FBX/Vaza%208067134/Vaza 8067134.fbx", function( object ) {
    const flower = this.scene.children.find(c => c.name === 'sunflower');
    window.sunflower = this.scene;
});


Tried the localhost way out of desperation

Comment: Try removing the `..`. It should now become `/assets/modelate_FBX/Vaza%208067134/Vaza 8067134.fbx`. Please also share your project structure.

Comment: Have attached the project here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I5BWkRhmPaerAlwbGUMJ8A4avugUr8Xc/view?usp=sharing

There are a multitude of FBX files, tried different files for testing.

I run it like said here https://codelabs.developers.google.com/ar-with-webxr#1

Chrome web server, connect phone, run through phone

Comment: Okay... let me take a look

Comment: I owe you one :) Thanks for the help

Comment: Hmm... why are you using `window.fbxLoader`? Why not do `fbxLoader`?

Comment: Thats how the boilerplate had the gltfLoader, adapted the code for fbxLoader

Comment: I see. Try without it?

Comment: Not working.. :(

Comment: The only thing we can try now is classic debugging. Try moving one of the fbx files (temporarily) to the same scope as your `js` file. Then try doing `window.fbxLoader.load("model.fbx", ...);` or `fbxLoader.load("model.fbx", ...);`

Comment: Hey @Anye, after some work i got to this:

app.js:96 Uncaught ReferenceError: sunflower is not defined
    at onSelect (app.js:96:5)
    at XRSession$1.dispatchEvent (<anonymous>:45:23)
    at Object.XRSession$1.<computed>.dispatchInputSourceEvent (<anonymous>:1364:28)
    at XRSession$1.<computed>.onSelectEnd (<anonymous>:1342:39)
    at EmulatedXRDevice.dispatchEvent (<anonymous>:45:23)
    at EmulatedXRDevice.onFrameStart (<anonymous>:36653:34)
    at XRSession$1.<computed>.onDeviceFrame (<anonymous>:1275:46)

.. Giving up for today; Will update you if I find a fix :D

Comment: Does it have anything to do with `const flower` and then doing `window.sunflower`? flower vs sunflower

Comment: Definetly not. It worked in the same way with the GLTF extension